# Get the number of posts shown in the current page

Tags: posts, pagination

I am currently trying to implement a load more function described in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374624/which-is-the-best-way-to-change-a-load-more-button-in-a-wordpress-theme), and in order to do so it is necessary to know how many post have been loaded already. Thus, I am trying to return the number of current posts in a given page.

The code in question is the following:

```
 <div class="row">
            <?php
            $posts = new WP_Query(array(
                'offset' => 0,
                'posts_per_page' => 6
            ));
            while ($posts->have_posts()) {
                $posts->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="card__wrapper col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
                    <?php get_template_part('partials/card', 'page'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php }
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>

<?php
        global $wp_query;
        // if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1)
            echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="misha_loadmore">More posts</div></div></div>'; // you can use <a> as well
        ?>
```

Even though, the WP_Query returns only 6 posts, the functions `get_query_var('posts_per_page')` and `$wp_query->post_count`, when called, return 10. Any ideas, what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `$posts` references to a *secondary/custom* WordPress query, so you should use `$posts->post_count` and not `$wp_query->post_count` which is for the main query.